# Differents aligns

Tags: math-mode, equations, enumerate

I have a problem trying to do this: I want to merge text and a two line equation (`aligned`) in a particular way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{,mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
First line equation &. \\
Second line equation &.  \quad \text{ Aligned text with this line very long long long 
long long long long and I don't want it to be out of paper}
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}

 \end{document}
```

This is my solution, but it only works when the text is short enough. And I want to be able to align text to first line too (not at the same time).

Besides I have a problem too trying to align items with numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
 $
 \begin{rcases}
  \begin{aligned}
1 \text{   I want ones  in the same line} & . \\
\text{And be able to aling things too} & . \\
  \end{aligned}
 \end{rcases}
 $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Would you please be clearer about what you'd like to obtain? There are three answers that look rather different from each other, probably because your problem is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

`rcases` is not the right tool for this, because it always creates a "vertically centered" object. Try this one, that uses `delarray` to emulate `rcases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delarray,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
 $
 \begin{array}[t].{@{}ll@{}}\}
1 & \text{I want ones  in the same line}\\
  & \text{And be able to align things too}\\
 \end{array}
 $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can either use `\parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   First line equation &. \\
   Second line equation &.  \quad \text{\parbox[t]{2in}{ Aligned text with this line
   very long long long long long long long and I don't want it to be out of paper}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

or, if your text it too long, `\intertext`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{,mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
   First line equation &.x \\
   \intertext{ Aligned text with this line very long long long 
               long long long long and I don't want it to be out of paper}
   Second line equation &. x\\
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hassan suggested you can use a `parbox` but if you don't want to number the equations a `tabular` could be another option to align mathematical expressions and text. In next example I use `tabularx` because this why you can fix total width of table and left the environment compute width of every column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
$x=2+y$ & Aligned text with this line very long long long 
long long long long and I don't want it to be out of paper \\
$x=\sqrt{3+y}+5y^2$ & Aligned text with this line very long long long 
long long long long and I don't want it to be out of paper
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am thinking I didn't explain properly how I want to mix it (besides this are a good solutions if there isn't what I want). In short, I want the equation and text mix like both are text, I mean, text continues under equation in next line.

Comment: @AsVHEn: If I understand and you want something like a `description` where the described items are equations. Try with `\begin{description}\item[$x=2+y$] Aligned text ... \end{description}`